# Tweepy - How to get only tweets with coordinates?

Tags: python, tweepy

I have a large database of tweet ids (a few million ids) and I need to get those that have location coordinates. I'm searching one by one, with the tweepy *lookup_statuses()* method, but it's a very slow process.

Is there a way to get just the ones with coordinates (property "place" or "coordinates")?

Comment: How do you get "coordinates" please? I am using `tweepy.StreamingClient.on_data()` which returns `""includes""` object with `"places"` and `"bbox"`. But I'm interested in the coordinates for the exact location. May be this is deprecated (can't use it): https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lookup_statuses` method accepts lists of 100 ids as argument (see the documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.lookup_statuses)), so you can do faster than getting them one by one.

But unfortunately, there is no other way to speed up your process.

Comment: I am using an instance of `tweepy.StreamingClient` class, to access `data` using `on_data()`. Currently, I can access returned json's `"includes"` object with "places" and "bbox". How do I get exact "coordinates" of tweet location please?